# Timezone example in broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I am trying to implement time zone change in broadcast receiver but its not working .my requirment is if i change the time zone it will go to another activity using broad cast receiver can anybody give example

Thanks

Comment: Does your error code say 'it doesn't work'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
In manifest:

        <receiver android:name=".TimeZoneChangedReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

In your `TimeZoneChangedReceiver` class:

   override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        var action : String? = intent.action
        var timeZone: String? = intent.getStringExtra("time-zone")
        Toast.makeText(context,action+timeZone,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Comment: It not going to other activity when i change the time zone

Comment: As JBM said its "android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" with no action. Take a look where it say constant value in the docs : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED

Comment: Update: On devices with API 26 and higher, the broadcast receiver register in the manifest will not be called. You need to do the registration runtime (in onCreate of your application maybe). This also means that your app will not be listening for these broadcasts if it's killed. It's also not a real solution to register it in a background service, as those are also limited on new devices. Not sure if there's a 100% equivalent solution nowadays...

Answer (score 3):

The correct intent filter is `"android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED"` (no "ACTION_" in the beginning).