# How to force Date doesn't change date after timezone change?

Tags: java, android, date

Example: my application contains two fragments. User actions:

1. In fragment1 user choose date (this date stores as a Date object)
2. User go to system settings and change timezone
3. User go back to application and press button in fragment1 (Date object passed to fragment2 and showed there in TextView)

Issue: date which was choosed by user and date which he see on fragment2 is different. For example:

- Initial timezone -11
- User choose 06/01/2015
- New timezone +13
- On fragment2 user see 06/02/2015

How to make that the Date doesn't changed after timezone change? Why it happens?

Comment: Could you share the relevant code? A `Date` has no concept of time zone; it's just a wrapper around a `long` value (milliseconds since Epoch in UTC).

Answer (score 1):

Dates are a matter of interpretation. You can store a date such that it includes the original timezone, or you can store it in UTC and then decide on output if you want to display it still in UTC or apply a new timezone (and possibly DSL). What yo do need is consistency.

Answer (score 1):

*Date* value is always UTC, regardless of the system time zone. When you display the date you can use *DateFormat* for converting the date to the system time zone.

You can register a *BroadcastReceiver* for **android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED** intent and reformat the date when timezone is changed. The value of your *Date* object remains the same, but *DateFormat* will format it to the new time zone

Update:

Example adopted from [Timezone example in broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598231/timezone-example-in-broadcast-receiver)

```
<receiver android:name=".TimeZoneChangedReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED " />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In TimeZoneChangedReceiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    Date now = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
    String formattedDate = format.format(now);
    mDateView.setText(formattedDate)
}
```

Comment: Could you please add simple example how to reformat the date when timezone is changed? Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to convert Date object only (in fragment1) without setting it into TextView? May be shift it mathematically?

Comment: Possible? Yes. Recommended? No!