# Is there an android event listener for change in the timezone of the device?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an android application. Here whenever the user changes the device timezone, I want a event listener to notify me? How can I accomplish it?

Comment: Can you explain your require why you required to listen notify when device timezone change?

Comment: i think this answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598231/timezone-example-in-broadcast-receiver

Answer (score 6):

Register a receiver with the following intent filters

```
filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
```

and register it in the `OnCreate` of your activity

```
public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);     
    }
```

Create a Broadcast receiver as follows.

```
 private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED) ||
                action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED))
            {
                doWorkSon();
            }
        }
    };
```

and unregister it in the `onDestroy` of your activity:

```
 public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(m_timeChangedReceiver);     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a BroadcastReceiver for intent action [ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED).  BroadcastReceiver is described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Answer (score 0):

In manifest file

```
<receiver
    android:name=".MyReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In myReceiver class

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            var action : String? = intent.action
            var timeZone: String? = intent.getStringExtra("time-zone")
            Toast.makeText(context,action+timeZone,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Comment: is it working ?